# Python associating location to user?

Tags: python, dictionary, location

I'm trying to associate latitude and longitude values to different users (I have multiple values of "check-ins" for each user) and I want to store them in a correct and efficient way so that I can easily access the information for each user in the future.

I'm new to Python and dont know exactly how this can be done.

For example, For each user I have:

```
<username> <latitude> <longitude>
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Create default dict of lists
import collections
users = collections.defaultdict(list)

# Add coordinates 10,20 to Bob
users['Bob'].append((10, 20))

print users['Bob']
>>> [(10,20)]

# Add coordinates 5,5 to Bob
users['Bob'].append((5, 5))


print users['Bob']
>>> [(10,20), (5,5)]
```

Comment: Excellent... Exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could store them in a database. Have a table for users and a table for checkins which has a ForeignKey to a user.

Comment: Yeah, but dont want to make it complicated. Anything easy that can be done (something like a dictionary with multiple values for each key?)

Answer (score 0):

How about a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)? Your user could be the key, and the other value could be a list consisting of the two location values.